# Attempting to flatten a tree in Haskell using in-order traversal

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

Trying to use the given fold function to flatten out a tree into a list.

```
treeFold :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFold _ b Leaf         = b
treeFold f b (Node lt x rt) = f (treeFold f b lt) x (treeFold f b rt)
```

Here is what I have tried to so far:

```
treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]
treeToList = treeFold (\xs x ys -> xs ++ x : ys) (\x -> [x])
```

For some reason, I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about doing this?
Feels like there's something I haven't quite gotten into my head about Haskell. Any help would be appreciated along with how to go about solving it.
Thanks!

Edit:

I realize that the type signature I am using here verges on the nonsensical. In the type signature of treeFold, based on what I can think, the second argument (b) is probably a list since it acts as the accumulator in a way in this case. That would make the third argument (Tree a) a some version of the argument on the left of the equation. Two of the arguments within the function have to be the left and right subtrees within a Node. The third argument is just the value of the Node. Within the function, I need to combine the left tree, right tree and the value in the usual in order fashion but all the different variations I tried have had some issues

Comment: what is `(\x -> [x])` doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types must fit:

```
treeFold ::           ( b -> a -> b -> b              ) -> b -> Tree a -> b

treeToList = treeFold (\xs   x    ys -> xs ++ (x : ys))    z
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                        b    a    b     b      a   b       b
                                              --------
                                              b
```

Since `x` and `ys` participate in the same `:`, their types must be compatible:

```
(:) ::   a  -> [a]  ->  [a]
x   ::   a
ys  ::          b
-------------------
              b ~ [a]
```

Thus we have

```
treeFold ::           ( [a] -> a -> [a] -> [a]           ) -> [a] -> Tree a->[a]

treeToList = treeFold (\ xs    x    ys  -> xs ++ (x : ys))     z
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                         [a]   a    [a]    [a]    a   [a]     [a]
                                                 --------
                                                 [a]
```

Conclusion: the last argument, `z`, must have the type `[a]`.

What is the meaning of this argument? As usual with the folds, each "variant" in the data type definition has a corresponding argument to the fold function.

Your (missing) data type definition is:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a)    a   (Tree a)       | Leaf
```

and the fold's type is

```
treeFold ::   (         b  ->  a  ->  b  -> b )   ->  b     -> Tree a -> b
```

which corresponds to the "*recursive results*-holding type" of

```
data TreeF a r = NodeF  r      a      r           | LeafF
```

Thus `z` is "the value to convert each `Leaf` to".

Most natural choice for it is just `[]`. Actually, the only choice, because we don't know anything about the type `a` (in `[a]`) yet.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I think I am still just beginning to wrap my head around the application of functions in Haskell and the way to reason about the arguments using the types provided. Thank you!

Comment: the main thing is, don't be afraid of the types! types are your friends! (for real, not like in that 'Mars Attacks!' movie :) ).  --- as for the application, mainly it's this: for `f :: a -> b -> c -> d`, we have `f (x::a) :: b -> c -> d`, and `f (x::a) (y::b) :: c -> d`, and `f (x::a) (y::b) (z::c) :: d`. that's all!

Answer (score 4):

The type of `treeFold` is

```
treeFold :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

You want to return a list of values, `[a]`.

Therefore the result type `b` must be equal to `[a]`, giving us a specialized type signature of

```
treeFold :: ([a] -> a -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Tree a -> [a]
```

Note that the second argument has type `[a]`.

What value are you passing instead?